# ORA-01008: not all variables bound Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

the below plsql code runs normally in the SQL developer window, but when i include in the package it fails

```
select sum(decode(refill_type,'EVD', recharge,'CUG',recharge,'EVD_BDL',recharge,'SOCH_BDL',recharge,0)) recharge_evd,
        sum(decode(refill_type,'VOUCHER',recharge,0)) recharge_physical,
        sum(decode(refill_type,'MOMO',recharge,'MOMO_BDL',recharge,0)) recharge_mfs,         
        sum(recharge) recharge_total
from        
( select nvl(a.refill_type,refill_category) refill_type, recharge 
    from fct_daily_refill a left join ceo_refill_segmentations b on (a.segmentation_id=b.segmentation_id) 
where date_key =:bdate  and is_refill=1

 union all

select 'MOMO_BDL' refill_type, trans_amt recharge
   from fct_cdr_subscriptions a left join dim_bundle ax on (a.bundle_name= ax.bundle_name) 
where ax.bundle_group like '%MOMO_BU%' and date_key =:bdate

    union all

select 'EVD_BDL' refill_type, trans_amt recharge
   from fct_cdr_subscriptions a         
  where date_key =:bdate     
    and upper(channel) like '%EVD%'

        union all

 select 'SOCH_BDL' refill_type, trans_amt recharge
   from fct_cdr_subscriptions a         
  where date_key =:bdate  
    and upper(channel) like '%SOCH%' );
```

Comment: In sql developer you will be prompted for the bind variables. In a package you don't use bind variables, you use arguments for the procedure.

Comment: What you have posted is not "PL/SQL code" so not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Developer, you write SQL and *SQL Developer* is the client, so it does the handling of the results that come back, plus the handling of getting your inputs into the query.

In a package, the *package* is now responsible for that, both getting values *into* the SQL and dealing with the results that come *back* from the SQL. Thus your SQL might end up looking like:

```
procedure MY_PROC(bdate in date) is

begin

for i in (
    select sum(decode(refill_type,'EVD', recharge,'CUG',recharge,'EVD_BDL',recharge,'SOCH_BDL',recharge,0)) recharge_evd,
            sum(decode(refill_type,'VOUCHER',recharge,0)) recharge_physical,
            sum(decode(refill_type,'MOMO',recharge,'MOMO_BDL',recharge,0)) recharge_mfs,         
            sum(recharge) recharge_total
    from        
    ( select nvl(a.refill_type,refill_category) refill_type, recharge 
        from fct_daily_refill a left join ceo_refill_segmentations b on (a.segmentation_id=b.segmentation_id) 
    where date_key =bdate  and is_refill=1

     union all

    select 'MOMO_BDL' refill_type, trans_amt recharge
       from fct_cdr_subscriptions a left join dim_bundle ax on (a.bundle_name= ax.bundle_name) 
    where ax.bundle_group like '%MOMO_BU%' and date_key =bdate

        union all

    select 'EVD_BDL' refill_type, trans_amt recharge
       from fct_cdr_subscriptions a         
      where date_key =bdate     
        and upper(channel) like '%EVD%'

            union all

     select 'SOCH_BDL' refill_type, trans_amt recharge
       from fct_cdr_subscriptions a         
      where date_key =bdate  
        and upper(channel) like '%SOCH%' )
)
loop
  --
  -- do what you need to do with the query output, which will be in:
  --
  -- i.recharge_evd, i.recharge_physical, i.recharge_mfs, i.recharge_total
  --
end loop;

end;
```

Comment: shouldn't that be without the ":" ? I get a "PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'bdate'" when compiling using the ":bindvar" syntax.

Comment: cut-paste fail on my part.  Corrected.